# APN Device Token stops receiveing any apns after some time

Tags: push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I have application which receives APNs from my server periodically. It calls registerForRemoteNotificationTypes at start and then reasking it periodically (while working). It correctly receives device token and sending it to backstage server for later use.

But there is a problem: 

- after app is started, it correctly recieves all apns sent from my server via device token generated by iphone at app start.

- but when app stays in background (without any restarts) for like 8-12 hours it stops to recieve anything 

- by checking app/server logs i see that app properly reasks for new token via registerForRemoteNotificationTypes periodically, properly receives exactly the same token it has from very start, backstage server continue to use it for sending apns and sending them to apple without any errors via socket

- but messages simply not showing on device any more, didReceiveRemoteNotification not called at all

- Exiting app manually and restarting it helps - registerForRemoteNotificationTypes return *another* token, which works very well - server uses it for sending apns and device immediately receives them, as expected.

so it seems like iphone reasking apple server for token only at app start and then hard-caching it. but token still have something like a ttl period.

is there any way to force iphone return fresh, actual device token every time app asking for it? how to force iphone to recheck device token on apple server to be sure it is really ok and healthy?

please help!

---

UPD: managed to narrow down problem
- app in question using sandbox apn environment (since we are developing it)
- i changed APN sending procedure to extended protocol and now see that after some time aplle sandbox server starting to reply with error 8 - invalid token. at the same time *device receiving the same old token from registerForRemoteNotification*. so there is definitely a problem with refreshing token by iOS

Answer (score 3):

after switching from sandbox environment to production one - problem is gone.
so there is a difference between sandbox and production gates: device token ttl in sandbox environment is much shorter than in production. still, device token on the phone itself is the same for both environments. so using sandbox environment makes this problem - phone returns invalid (already invalidated on server) device token for application